# error 404 after login to admin, nginx and index.php issue, how to solve

Tags: magento-1.8, error, nginx, 404-page, admin-panel

I did set NGINX for my server, and use DirectAdmin, also I changed `nginx.conf` for Magento configs, everything is ok but I have a problem with admin area!

I can not login to dashboard, login page appear only when I write in url admin without `index.php`, example:

```
http://www.example.com/adminurl/
```

but when I click on login, then url change to:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/adminurl/
```

and page return 404 error!

How can I solve this issue?

Use NGINX instead of apache and in frontend every link work as well, but all of them working without `index.php`

Comment: After login you are redirecting to 404 ?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is caused by index.html and index.php my solution a problem I had yesterday may help with this

[500 Internal Server Error when trying to access admin pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32976/500-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-access-admin-pages/33119#33119)

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening in frontend too?. I think is a problem with your nginx conf in rewriting URL, Did you have url write in magento set to yes? If you can give us more information would be great.
Here is a copy of an old magento nginx conf. Just remove the things that you don't need.

```
server {                                              
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name "Server name";

    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tenlinea.key;
    #ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_news/t_enlinea.crt;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    #ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    index index.php;
   root   "Your root";                                     

location = /apc.php {
    deny all;
}  
        ## maintenance mode ##
         ######################

            set $maintenance on;
        #    if ($remote_addr ~ (8.8.8.8|8.8.4.4)) {
        #        set $maintenance off;              
        #    }                                      
        #    if ($uri ~ ^/(index.php/)?(paypal)/(.*)$ ) {
        #        set $maintenance off;                   
        #    }                                           
        #    if ($maintenance = on) {                    
        #        return 503;                             
        #    }                                           
        #    location /maintenance {}                    
        #    error_page 503 @maintenance;                
        #    location @maintenance {                     
        #        root /var/public_html/domain.com/maintenance;
        #        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;            
        #    }                                                

        ##########################                            
        ## end maintenance mode ##                            
        location /nginx_status {
        # Turn on stats
        #stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        # only allow access from 192.168.1.5 #
        #allow 127.0.0.1;
        #deny all;
        allow all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                 try_files $uri =204;
        }                            
        location / {                 
        index index.html index.php; 


        ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404; # @handler;                       
         #try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
          expires max; ## Enable max file cache                
        }                                                   

        ## These locations need to be denied
            location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
            location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
            location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
            #location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
            location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
            location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
            location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

        ## Allow admins only to view export directory
        ## Set up the password for any username using this command:
        ## htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/htpasswd magentoadmin            

        location /var/export/ { 
                auth_basic           "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## Defined at /etc/nginx/htpassword
                autoindex            on;                                          
            }                                                                     

        ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
       ## location  /. {
               ## return 404;
           ## }
        ## Magento uses a common front handler

    location /api {
    }
        ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        location ~ .php/ {
                rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;

            }

        ## php-fpm parsing
        location ~ \.php$ {
    ####fastcgi_read_timeout 30000; 
    fastcgi_read_timeout 30000;
        ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

        ## Disable cache for php files
        expires        off;

        ## php-fpm configuration
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/magento$fastcgi_script_name;
        #include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        ###fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        ###fastcgi_index index.php;
        ###fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        # Store code is located at Administration > Configuration > Manage Stores in your Magento Installation.
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

        ## Tweak fastcgi buffers, just in case.
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        #add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
     access_log off;
        }
    ##
    # Rewrite for versioned CSS+JS via filemtime
    ##
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        #rewrite ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 last;
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    ##
    # Aggressive caching for static files
    # If you alter static files often, please use 
    # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    ##
    location ~* \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|t?gz|tif|tiff|ttf|wav|webm|wma|woff|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your phpmyadmin from your host try once this sql command...

Run this Sql

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Now admin can able to login.